# In memory workspace in R?

Tags: r, command-line

I want to repetitively call R code to build a data.frame and once it is built, I want to perform some other operations on it.

For example, I have a script `xyz.R` which enters a new row in a data.frame every time it is executed. It gets the new row from a command line argument sent to it. If I can execute `xyz.R` 10 times, I want the data.frame to have 10 rows. Once it has 10 rows, I want to aggregate the data using another R script `abc.R`.

But once a R script is done executing, the workspace is destroyed. We can save the workspace and load it again but that will consume time. I want to do this in-memory and without saving the workspace on storage. Can it be done?

Comment: You might want to rewrite those scripts into functions. Alternatively you can use `source` to execute code from a script. This should not 'destroy' your workspace.

Comment: @Axeman, how will I access command line parameters repetitively when I write the script as functions? Also, I am using shell to run R executables, how can I source them?

Comment: @Axeman also if I use source, how will I get the new command line arguments?

Comment: Perhaps you can give a short reproducible example.